# Obtain Original First Entry URL Href Hit While User Keeps Navigating between Different Pages

Tags: javascript, browser, query-string, tracking

Background: I have a website, say https://example.com, which has different pages. E.g. user firstly came to the site with URL https://example.com/page-a?utm=google, then user continue browsing other pages e.g. /page-b, /page-c.

Problem: In other pages, e.g., /page-b, how can I know the user's original first hit URL (which is https://example.com/page-a?utm=google). Can I obtain from the browser easily?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated this one for quick a bit. And I think this trick can help the case. Apply the session Storage logic to each page, so add the following code to each page of the website:

```
<script>
  if (!sessionStorage.getItem("entryURL")) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("entryURL", document.location.href);
  }
</script>
```

Then in each page, can access from `sessionStorage.getItem("entryURL")`